# 404 error on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404

When [this page](http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/) loads, the following appears in Firebug:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://summer-festivals.cloudfoundry.com/undefined
```

I've tracked down the error to the [JQuery plugin](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/12/30/huge-updates-to-jquery-infinite-carousel-version-2-released/) that renders the carousel. If I remove this plugin and the code that calls it, the error disappears.

However, I can't figure out what the plugin is trying to retrieve that causes the error. All the images that the carousel itself uses (e.g. for the prev, next, pause buttons), and the images the carousel displays load correctly, and I can't think what else it might be trying to download.

Comment: I'm guessing from the undefined that it is trying to form a url or similar using an undefined property of something. There's not a null entry in an array somewhere or an incorrect length indicator (eg saying that you have ten images when you only have 9) is there? Pretty obvious thoughts but you may not have thought of them...

Comment: @Chris it probably is something like that, but the error message doesn't give a line number and I didn't write the plugin, so I really don't know where to start

Comment: There also appears to be a newer version of that plugin available at that site. You might want to test that out as well.

Comment: @j08691 I tested out the newer version, but it also generates a 404, even on the plugin's own demo pages http://www.catchmyfame.com/jquery/infinitecarousel3/demo/d1.html

Comment: According to Chrome's network tools it looks like the 404 may come from a missing wait.gif (wait.gif /jquery/infinitecarousel3/demo/images GET 404 Not Found). Seems like the wait.gif is used as a background image while the carousel images are loading. You can probably either remove it from the plugin or just use your own.

Comment: @j08691 yes, the problem with v3 is definitely wait.gif, but I'm using v2 where the problem is something else

Answer (score 1):

AFter doing a bit of debugging (all praise firebug) I narrowed it down to the for loop starting on line 175:

```
for(i=0;i<=numImages-1;i++)
{
thumb = $('img:eq('+(i+1)+')', obj).attr('src');
// $('#thumbs'+randID).append('<div class="thumb" id="thumb'+randID+'_'+(i+1)+'" style="cursor:pointer;background-image:url('+thumb+');display:inline;float:left;width:'+o.thumbnailWidth+';height:'+o.thumbnailHeight+';line-height:'+o.thumbnailHeight+';padding:0;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;border:2px solid #ccc;margin-right:4px;font-size:'+o.thumbnailFontSize+';font-family:Arial;color:#000;text-shadow:0 0 3px #fff">'+(i+1)+'</div>');
$('#thumbs'+randID).append('<div class="thumb" id="thumb'+randID+'_'+(i+1)+'" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline;float:left;width:'+o.thumbnailWidth+';height:'+o.thumbnailHeight+';padding:0;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;border:2px solid #ccc;margin-right:4px;font-size:'+o.thumbnailFontSize+';font-family:Arial;color:#000;text-shadow:0 0 3px #fff"><img src="'+thumb+'" width="'+o.thumbnailWidth+'" height="'+o.thumbnailHeight+'" alt="" /></div>');
// $('#thumbs'+randID).append('<div class="thumb" id="thumb'+randID+'_'+(i+1)+'" style="cursor:pointer;display:inline;float:left;width:'+o.thumbnailWidth+';height:'+o.thumbnailHeight+';padding:0;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;border:2px solid #ccc;margin-right:4px;font-size:'+o.thumbnailFontSize+';font-family:Arial;color:#000;text-shadow:0 0 3px #fff"><img src="thumbnail.php?i='+thumb+'&w='+o.thumbnailWidth+'&h='+o.thumbnailHeight+'&q=100" alt="" /></div>');
if(i<=o.inView) $('#thumb'+randID+'_'+i).css({'border-color':'#ff0000'});
unviewable.push(i+1);
}
```

The upshot of where it seems to go wrong is in the `i+1` in the selector. `obj` is `div#carousel` and this has 9 images (`numImages` is correctly set to 9).

However the selector loops from 1 to 9 whereas I believe it should loop from 0 to 8 (jsut by sticking stuff in the watch window). This means that when it gets to evaluating `$('img:eq(9)', obj)` it gets nothing back so the src attribute is "undefined". It then tries to add an image with "undefined" as the src whcih is where it goes wrong.

It looks like a bug in the carousel code so I'd probably suggest trying to talk to them about it. You might be able to fix it just by replacing the i+1 with i but I offer no guarantees on that. :)

Comment: Great job, now that I know roughly where the bug is, hopefully I can fix it. Any idea why Firebug didn't indicate the line number of the error?

Comment: I've no idea, I'm afraid. I just found it by stepping through various bits until I got the error and then jumped into that bit of code and repeated. Only thing I can think of is that it was in anonymous functions and such like so maybe the JS engine lost track of where they originally came from. That sort of thing is over my head though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your main library calls in your header tag before you call all your resources.

These should all still be in your header.  Your document ready() stuff can stay in the footer.  See if this fixes your issue.

```
<script src="/static/js/namespace.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/global.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/slide.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/superfish/hoverIntent.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/superfish/superfish.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/superfish/supersubs.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/tablesorter/jquery.metadata.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>
<script src="/static/js/tablesorter/init.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" >     </script>
<script src="/static/js/carousel/jquery.infinitecarousel2-thumbmod-1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```